# Ion-select multiple=“true” does not function within ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic3

I notice that when attempt to use ion-select within ngFor on a list that is set dynamically with a function, the lists did not get rendered to the DOM.

On the other hand, the DOM renders correctly if I take the individual element outside of the ngFor construct, OR if I do not use multiple=“true”.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Example:
1/ Fails to render:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let t of getMyListOfFields()">
  <ion-label>{{t.FieldName}}</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY/MM/DD" [(ngModel)]="t.FieldValue" *ngIf="t.DataType == 'date'"></ion-datetime>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="t.FieldValue" *ngIf="!t.LookupID && t.DataType != 'date'"></ion-input>
  <ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="t.FieldValue" *ngIf="t.LookupID">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let l of t.Lookups" [value]="l.ID">{{l.Text}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

2/ Renders correctly:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Test List</ion-label>
  <ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="model.TestItem.FieldValue"  *ngIf="model.TestItem && model.TestItem.LookupID">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let l of model.TestItem.Lookups" [value]="l.ID">{{l.Text}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: You seem to have a bit of a typo here: `getMyListOfFields()')`

Comment: Thanks @SurajRao, I changed the name of the function in my post for anonymity. It is correct in my code and I now corrected the typo too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for those interested, I find a workaround to the issue. If I replace the function call and provide a static list instead in the ngFor, there are no issues and the DOM renders, with the multi-select functioning correctly.

Curious why the function call would prevent it from rendering correctly. Is there a bug somewhere?